# draw control inside another using its graphics

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, controls, awt

I'm basically trying to draw a JComponent inside another by calling the second component's paint passing it the first component's Graphics.

I'm trying to create a GUI editor, (reinventing the wheel, I know, it's just a proof of concept)
So I have a class that extends JPanel where I want to draw components from a VectorControls.

So far I got this method in my extended JPanel:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Sketch extends JPanel {
    private Vector<JComponent> controls = new Vector<JComponent>();

    public Sketch() {
        super();
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    }

    public void addControl(JComponent c) {
        Dimension d = new Dimension(100,50);
        c.setPreferredSize(d);
        c.setMinimumSize(d);
        c.setMaximumSize(d);
        controls.add(c);
        this.repaint();
        this.revalidate();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for(int i=controls.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
            JComponent c = controls.get(i);
            c.paint(g);
        }       
    }
}
```

I'm building/attaching the Sketch panel like this:

```
public GUIEditor() {
  mainFrame = new JFrame("GUI EDITOR");
  mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  Sketch mainPanel = new Sketch();
  mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640,480));

  GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
  GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

  mainFrame.setLayout(gbl);

  JPanel toolsPanel = new JPanel();
  toolsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160,480));
  toolsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));      

  for(Control c : toolBoxItems ) {
      AbstractAction action = new ToolBoxButtonAction(mainPanel, c.type);
      JButton b = new JButton(action);
      b.setText(c.title);
      toolsPanel.add(b);
  }

  gbc.gridx = 0;
  gbc.gridy = 0;
  gbl.setConstraints(mainPanel, gbc);
  mainFrame.add(mainPanel);

  gbc.gridx = 1;
  gbc.gridy = 0;
  gbl.setConstraints(toolsPanel, gbc);
  mainFrame.add(toolsPanel);

  mainFrame.pack();
  mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Inside ToolBoxButtonAction, basically I'm doing this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
        sketch.addControl(control.newInstance());
    } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but I'm writing this because it doesn't work.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Is `Controls` a class or an `ArrayList<JComponent>`? If it's a list, it should be declared as `controls` (lowercase) for easy readability.

Comment: *it doesn't work* What happened?

Comment: @johnchen902 it doesn't work because I don't see anything drawn to my JPanel

Comment: @WChargin Sorry for the uppercase, I'm switching from C# to Java back and forth everyday (work/home) I got confused there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm basically trying to draw a JComponent inside another by calling the second component's paint passing it the first component's Graphics.

Components can only be painted when the component has non-zero size. Normally the size of a component is determined by the layout manager.

Your basic code looks reasonable, but unless you have code to size and locate the components you won't see anything. If you just set the size then all components will paint on top of one another.

Or the problem may be that your parent panel doesn't have a size so it is not even painted. The default FlowLayout uses the preferred size of the child components to determine the panels size. Since you don't add components directly to the panel there are no child components so the preferred size will be 0. When you reinvent the wheel you need to reinvent everything.

Without a SSCCE the context of how you use this code is unknown to all we can do is guess.

Edit:

Create a SSCCE when you have a problem and get it working with hard coded values before trying to get it to work dynamically. Something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Sketch extends JComponent
{
    private Vector<JComponent> controls = new Vector<JComponent>();

    public void addControl(JComponent c)
    {
        c.setSize(100, 50);
        int location = controls.size() * 50;
        c.setLocation(location, location);
        controls.add(c);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for(int i=controls.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            JComponent c = controls.get(i);
            Point location = c.getLocation();
            g.translate(location.x, location.y);
            c.paint(g);
            g.translate(-location.x, -location.y);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        Sketch sketch = new Sketch();
        sketch.addControl( new JButton("button") );
        sketch.addControl( new JTextField(10) );
        sketch.addControl( new JCheckBox("Checkbox") );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sketch");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( sketch );
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited to reflect how it's implemented. As you can see I assign a size to the Sketch panel. I have to say that if I add the JComponent directly (using the inherited "add" method) it is shown correctly, but I don't want it to become a "real" JComponent, I just need its image.

Comment: btw, I know I'll have to translate the Graphics object to get everything in its correct place, for now I'm happy if I can get all components piled somewhere.

Comment: @マルちゃんだよ, you still haven't posted a SSCCE. See my edit for an example of a SSCCE.

Comment: Nice! you got it working! Please edit your answer to reflect that I was mistaking here: "c.setPreferredSize(d);  c.setMinimumSize(d); c.setMaximumSize(d);" I did a "c.setSize(d);" just like you did and it displayed the components correctly. Strange but that was it... I was also able to break your SSCCE by replacing that very method.

Comment: @マルちゃんだよ, Its not strange, I mentioned that you needed to set the size in my first sentence. The other properties are used by layout managers only to determine the size.

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago, I've written a framework for such tasks. Maybe you find it useful (the library is Open Source):

Tutorial:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/current/docs/tutorial/swing/customizer/index.html

Javadoc:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/current/docs/api/softsmithy-lib-swing-customizer/index.html

Info about the latest release:

http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/2012/11/news-from-software-smithy-version-03.html

Comment: Very nice work! My idea is to implement it using a UMLET (http://www.umlet.com/) style for editing, mixing it with a XAML style for the formatting of the forms info files.